# I have made a proxy scraper in PHP but I don't know how to check if the proxy is live

Tags: php

The below code scrapes the proxy from the website but what I want is the program to check if the proxy is alive or not one by one and then save that proxy in the file. Can someone help me out to do so

```
<?php

header('Content-Type:application/json'); 
$url = "https://www.my-proxy.com/free-proxy-list.html"; 
 
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/'.rand(111,999).'.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.'.rand(1111,9999).'.104 Safari/'.rand(111,999).'.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

$proxies = array();
$firstcount = 1;
$endcound = 10;
for ($i = $firstcount; $i <= $endcound; $i++){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.my-proxy.com/free-proxy-list-$i.html"); 
    $result =curl_exec($ch);
  

    ///Get Proxy 
    // >102.64.122.214:8085#U
    preg_match_all("!\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}:.\d{2,4}!", $result, $matches);
    $proxies = array_merge($proxies, $matches[0]);
}
curl_close($ch);
print_r($proxies);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to test, easiest one being an option in 'file_get_contents' request

```
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://' . $prox,   //IP:PORT info. ie: 8.8.8.8:2222
        'timeout' => 2,
    'request_fulluri' => true,
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$base_url='http://lotsofrandomstuff.com/1.php'; //url that simply returns '1' each time
$web=@file_get_contents($base_url,false,$context); 
if($web=='1')
   {
        echo "proxy is good";
   }

else
{
        echo "proxy is dead";
}
```

Comment: Yes but i want to save all the good proxies in the file how can i do that?

Comment: Now, what's your question here? How to check for "good proxies" or how to write them to a file? Please clarify your problem.